# How to load a web page into another web page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-applications

I want to be able to load a webpage (with many asp:controls) into a panel of my main web application. Basically from a user menu, the corresponding webpage will be loaded. So far I've tried the following...

1. IFrame - this doesn't keep the view states of the controls
2. Creating dynamic controls as opposed to web pages, but very slow with alot of    controls because you have to re-create every control on a postback.

Is there a reasonable way to accomplish this?

Comment: Are you needing to load a full page within another page, or are you trying to do partial page posts/gets?  i.e. the user click's a button and only part of the page is updated? (similar to how comments work on SO)

Comment: @KenHenderson Ideally I would like to load either a WebUserControl or WebPage.aspx and its code behind. The Page basically contians a verical set(10 to 100) of random controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're working with ASP.NET web forms based upon the control specifics in your question.

From what you've described it sounds like you want to add a [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) control to your current page.  The update panel could host your custom [UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.aspx), this would most likely help with page responsiveness (generally this is what the [TreeView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.aspx) control does).

That being said unless the data source for your dynamic controls is slow (or the web server is overloaded) a hundred dynamic controls shouldn't kill your page render times.  I've written pages that use in excess of 100 dynamic controls against a SharePoint instance and it was reasonably responsive.  Keep in mind that all server side controls are class instances that are created, loaded, rendered (skipped a bunch of [lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) events but you get the idea).

Comment: Yes Asp.Net is correct. I'm having issue with postback time. When I use the Ajax Combobox's and have many controls (100+) the post back takes along time, over 10 seconds. Do you have some examples to share?

Comment: @tszoro, there are examples on how to use UpdatePanel on the linked page.  My suggestion would be to profile your page performance and figure out what is causing the problem, here is one link that has some profiling suggestions, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/synergist/archive/2007/12/03/profiling-asp-net-page-loading-time.aspx,  others are easily found searching for `asp.net page profiling` on a search engine.